# How do I download an entire folder with aria2?

Tags: linux, wget, aria2

[Aria2](http://aria2.sourceforge.net/manual/en/html/) is a great `wget` replacement, having a lot of features like multi-threading, split download,download resume, etc

But having all this features and option can make it hard to do some specific commands.

I want to download this [XOWA](http://xowa.sourceforge.net/) entire folder from here with 10 simultaneous downloads, and the file split in 4 segments from this directory: https://archive.org/download/Xowa_enwiki_latest

To download a single file split in 4 segments I use:

```
aria2c -s 4 -x 4 https://archive.org/download/Xowa_enwiki_latest/Xowa_enwikibooks_2015-04-07.7z
```

But I want to download all the directory much like the `wget -r` option does but with 10 concurrent download files and 4 segment download per each file, how can I do that using Aria2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`aria2c` does not support *recursive* download. It does not read the downloaded resource to extract links to other resources.

You can prepare the list of links in a text file and then pass it to `aria2c` to download.

For more info, see [Input File](https://aria2.github.io/manual/en/html/aria2c.html#id2) section in aria2 documentation.